# Closure in a certain topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathcal{T}_3=$ the topology having as basis all open rays $(- \infty, a)$

What is the closure of $A=(2,\sqrt{7})$ in the above topology ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.** Every nontrivial closed set of this space is of the form $[a,\infty)$.

Comment: So is it $[2,\infty)$ ?

Comment: @Carpediem Yes, you are right. Can you describe why the closure of $A$ is $[2,\infty)$?